# bash: ~/.bash_profile: No such file or directory

Tags: bash

I keep getting this error:

```
bash: ~/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
```

Here is my bash_profile:

```
alias ngrok=/Users/mmahalwy/Desktop/Code/ngrok

export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced

alias ls='ls -GFh'

function prompt {
  local BLACK="\[\033[0;30m\]"
  local BLACKBOLD="\[\033[1;30m\]"
  local RED="\[\033[0;31m\]"
  local REDBOLD="\[\033[1;31m\]"
  local GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"
  local GREENBOLD="\[\033[1;32m\]"
  local YELLOW="\[\033[0;33m\]"
  local YELLOWBOLD="\[\033[1;33m\]"
  local BLUE="\[\033[0;34m\]"
  local BLUEBOLD="\[\033[1;34m\]"
  local PURPLE="\[\033[0;35m\]"
  local PURPLEBOLD="\[\033[1;35m\]"
  local CYAN="\[\033[0;36m\]"
  local CYANBOLD="\[\033[1;36m\]"
  local WHITE="\[\033[0;37m\]"
  local WHITEBOLD="\[\033[1;37m\]"
  local RESETCOLOR="\[\e[00m\]"

  export PS1="\n$RED\u $PURPLE@ $GREEN\w $BLUE[\#] → $RESETCOLOR"
  export PS2="| → $RESETCOLOR"
}

# prompt

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

source ~/.git-completion.bash

if [ -f `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion
fi


source ~/.profile
source /Users/mmahalwy/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Comment: Set `PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+'; set -x` to get line numbers printed, and reproduce.

Comment: that said, I'd guess that somewhere, you're quoting a `~` that needs to be unquoted to expand. (For this reason, I tend to favor `$HOME` over `~` in scripts).

Comment: anyhow -- I wouldn't be surprised if your problem weren't in this particular file at all, but in something else that was trying to invoke your `.bash_profile`, but quoting the `~` used to do so, and thus doing so incorrectly.

Comment: Another way to track this down: Run `PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+' bash -x -i` at your shell, and see exactly what the line above the error message says.

Comment: BTW -- instead of editing in your own answer as part of the question, add it as an answer (if you think this is still of use to other people, given the way it was answered; as it is, deleting it is probably appropriate).

Comment: What do you do when you get this error?

Answer (score 20):

Bash has `~/.profile` instead of `~/.bash_profile`

Content of `~/.profile` :

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Comment: Bash will use the first available -- if there's no `.bash_profile`, it falls back to `.profile`. In this case, of course, the `.bash_profile` explicitly sources the `.profile`.

Comment: `root@debian:/home/mohsen/test# ls /etc/skel/ -a
.  ..  .bash_logout  .bashrc  .profile`

Comment: But for run in your `home dir`

Comment: Does this mean I don't have bash? `-bash: /Users/scottlydon/.profile: No such file or directory`

Comment: Oh, you have mac. in Linux box, you can find it in `ls /etc/skel/ -a` , Then you can copy them into your home dir. But I don't know where it is on mac. @ScottyBlades

Comment: This answer should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

The problem was a trailing `"~/.bash_profile" 38L, 1070C` which I had copied by mistake from vim.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was receiving the following error.

```
-bash: /Users/mac241/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/mac241/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory
```

After few checks, I got to know when I created `.bash_profile` file, below two commands already was prewritten on the file.

```
source /Users/mac241/.rvm/scripts/rvm
source /Users/mac241/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

based on error, I got to know this are the problems and after I removed, It started working. Hope you are written and defined those commands only which you required to auto run up on shell start.